# ASP.NET Core WebApi : AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints

Tags: asp.net-web-api, routes, http-get

I've this controller code in a standard .NET Core WebApi project:

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class MessageController : ControllerBase
{
  [HttpGet]
  public string GetByTransactionId([FromRoute(Name = "transactionId")] string transactionId)
  {
    return "transactionId";
  }

  [HttpGet]
  public string GetByNumber([FromRoute(Name = "number")] string number)
  {
    return "number";
  }
}
```

And I want to access the api like:

- https://localhost:44316/Message?transactionId=abc
- https://localhost:44316/Message?number=foobar

When accessing the endpoint-url like: https://localhost:44316/Message?transactionId=abc, I get error like:

```
AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches:

Server.Controllers.MessageController.GetByTransactionId (Server)
Server.Controllers.MessageController.GetByNumber (Server)
```

Can this be solved by using the correct with `[HttpGet]` or `[Route]` attributes?

Answer (score 2):

```cs
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[Message]")]
    public class MessageController : ControllerBase
    {
      [HttpGet]
      [Route("transactionId")]
      public string GetByTransactionId([FromRoute(Name = "transactionId")] string transactionId)
      {
        return "transactionId";
      }
    
      [HttpGet]
      [Route("number")]
      public string GetByNumber([FromRoute(Name = "number")] string number)
      {
        return "number";
      }
    }
```

Try with `Route`-attribute . this will sort out your problem

Comment: Sorry, this does not work for me. I get a 404 now on both urls.

Comment: the api urls you access is wrong. try with this .https://localhost:44316/controller/GetByTransactionId?transactionId=abc

Comment: But in my situation, I want to access both endpoints on /Message

Comment: i have modified code and try now.(please make sure spelling of routes are exactly same in your request)

Comment: I am using Swagger and it won't run at all now - Failed to load API - 500 https://localhost:9999/swagger/v1/swagger.json